# Snow on the Yukon roads in summer

Tags: canada, driving, snow, summer, yukon

I am planning a trip in Yukon during the summer (July to September) and I wonder what I can expect in terms of road conditions and what specific equipment (for the car) I would need.

I found out that [winter tires are never required in Yukon](https://www.save.ca/community/when-winter-tires-are-required-in-each-canadian-province/) even though I assume that in winter, it is very useful if not essential.

What about the summer? Do drivers there tend to use winter tires all-year-round? Would it be useful to have some?

Is there any other equipment that would be useful like a shovel to remove the snow? I assume there would not be that much snow in summer over there, though.

I plan on driving mostly on Highway 1 or 2, i.e. most likely not north of Dawson City.

Comment: This is much too broad, and risks being closed. Whole books have been written on the subject. See, for example, The Milepost _https://www.themilepost.com_

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. Is it too broad because of the size of the territory? Or of the time frame? Or the words used (do I need vs. is it more comfortable)? I have found that winter tires are never mandatory in Yukon (!), I have found the 511 website but it only gives the current road conditions. I assume people living or traveling to Yukon don't read a whole book to figure the density of gas stations or the need for winter tires all-year-round

Comment: I think it's too broad because it asks too many questions about too many topics. This isn't the sort of focused question (with an absolute answer) that the site craves. Take a look at the Help files: _travel.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask_ and _travel.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic_.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica I've updated my question to make it less broad. The milepost is very useful, thank you for that resource. If I may have a critic, I have found your last comment too vague, too broad, not very helpful. I've used this website a lot so I know better how to improve a question, but I believe a new user would have been lost.

Comment: Regulations are sometimes so comical, I live on the southern Vancouver Island and we get snow maybe once or twice in a season if that. There are still highways and roads where winter tires are required between Oct and March.

While I've personally never been to the Yukon, I suspect that even without the needless regulation people still put on winter tires (because common sense).

Comment: Have you tried asking https://reddit.com/r/Yukon or [Yukon's Department of Tourism & Culture](https://www.travelyukon.com/en/contact-us)? > **If have any questions and want to connect with someone from our team, please contact at us here:**
> > - Email: [vacation@gov.yk.ca](mailto:vacation@gov.yk.ca "vacation@gov.yk.ca")
> - Call: Yukon Visitor Information Centre toll-free number: [1-800-661-0494](tel:1-800-661-0494)
> - Text: [1-866-677-6804](tel:1-866-677-6804)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dawson City doesn't have snow from July to August. It can snow a tad in September.

https://weatherspark.com/y/282/Average-Weather-in-Dawson-City-Canada-Year-Round#Sections-Precipitation

> [image]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dawson_City#Geography

> [image]

In general, there are [4 Reasons Not to Drive Winter Tires In Summer - Les Schwab](https://www.lesschwab.com/article/4-reasons-not-to-drive-winter-tires-through-summer.html).

> #### 1. Winter Tires Can Wear Faster in Warmer Temperatures
>
> [Winter tires](https://www.lesschwab.com/tires/winter) are made with a special rubber compound that helps deliver maximum grip in snowy and icy conditions by staying pliable in colder temperatures. Heat is really hard on winter tires, which are meant to be used when temperatures are ~45°F or below. Winter tires that are run on hot pavement tend to wear out much faster.
>
> [image: Differences between all-season and winter tires]
>
> Winter tires are designed for traction, not longevity, whereas [all-season tires](https://www.lesschwab.com/tires/all-season) are designed for lower rolling resistance and longer tread life. These tires are made with a rubber compound that is designed for a wide range of temperatures and road conditions.
>
> Driving winter tires in the summer can wear them out faster. That’s because the rubber compound in winter tires is designed for colder conditions, not warmer temperatures.
>
> ### 2. It Will Cost You, Not Save You Money
>
> If you’ve made the investment in the added safety of winter tires, changing them out with a set of all-season or summer tires at the right time will help extend the service life of the winter tires — saving you money.
>
> Compared to all-season tires, winter tires often have a higher rolling resistance, which can cost you at the gas pump.
>
> ### 3. Traction and Handling Issues
>
> The softer rubber compound in winter tires won’t deliver as crisp of handling as an all-season tire. Cornering, acceleration, and braking may be compromised on hot, summer roads and higher temperatures.
>
> When it comes to traction, lack of [tread depth](https://www.lesschwab.com/article/tire-tread-and-the-useful-penny-test.html) can be a bigger safety risk in winter. If you do use winter tires in the summer, you can expect those tires to have less tread for the following winter. That means your tires won’t channel snow, slush or water as well.
>
> ### 4. Swapping Tires Can Be Easy and Free
>
> Swapping out winter tires for all-season or performance tires twice a year is easy. When you have Les Schwab tires on wheels, we’ll do it for free. We may even be able to store your tires at [select locations](https://www.lesschwab.com/tire-storage).

[CAA Quebec](https://www.caaquebec.com/en/on-the-road/advice/tips-and-tricks/tip-and-trick/show/sujet/driving-on-winter-tires-in-summer-a-risky-venture/).

> Winter tires are made of a thermal rubber that is designed especially  to maintain its elasticity when the mercury falls, giving them superior road-adherence qualities in cold weather. This rubber, however, degenerates much more quickly when the temperature rises. If you decide to keep your winter tires on all year, the tread-wear indicators showing it’s time to buy new tires will appear more quickly, generally after less than 10,000 kilometres.

> Winter tires provide greater road resistance, which not only makes them noisier while driving but impacts fuel consumption.

> So keeping them on year-round is far less economical than it may seem.  If you’re looking to save a few dollars, you’re better to do the annual tire changeovers yourself.

> Exposing the rubber in winter tires to heat increases the risk of a blowout, which can cause the driver to lose control of the vehicle. The risks of aquaplaning also rise, since winter tire treads don’t shed water  as effectively as those of summer or all-season tires.
> CAA-Quebec conducted a study aimed at assessing the effectiveness of winter tires used in summer in comparison with that of all-season tires used during the same period.

> The results show that the braking distance of a winter tire in summer is longer than that of an all-season tire, especially on a wet road surface. For example, a vehicle equipped with winter tires travelling at 100 km/h in the rain will require a braking distance of 93.8 metres, compared with 74.3 metres on all-season tires — a 26% difference! Because the tests were conducted on new tires at a temperature of 20°C, it is daunting to think about the risks of driving with winter tires during a heat wave!

> The CAA-Quebec study also shows that driving with winter tires in summer makes avoidance manoeuvres more difficult in emergency situations. Because tire treads soften in hot conditions, the  vehicle will tend to drift if the driver attempts to make an abrupt manoeuvre.

> So switching your tires at the onset of the warm weather is strongly advised, for your own and others’ safety.

[What is the Risks of Driving Your Winter Tires in Summer ? | Point S](https://point-s.ca/en/blog-and-advices/the-risks-of-driving-your-winter-tires-in-summer/)

> **What happens when you drive on winter tires in summer?**
>
> - Winter tires are designed work best in the cold and are less effective at dissipating heat, so the risks of [overinflating](https://point-s.ca/en/blog-and-advices/vehicles-recommended-tire-inflation-pressure/) and blowouts are much higher.
> - The rubber compound is much more flexible, which affects how your vehicle handles and feels on the road, especially when you make sudden turns, which often results in a loss of control.
> - Since the rubber compound is softer, the tread changes shape more. This creates more rolling resistance and uses more gas.
> - When you drive on winter tires in summer, you reduce their lifespan by close to 60 per cent, as opposed to if they were only used in winter conditions.
> - [Tire technology](https://point-s.ca/en/blog-and-advices/winter-tires-a-closer-look-at-innovations/) has come a long way, but winter tires are still much noisier than summer or all‑season tires.

[Can You Drive Snow and Winter Tires Year Round? | Bridgestone Tires](https://www.bridgestonetire.com/tread-and-trend/drivers-ed/driving-winter-tires-year-round)

> #### Why You Shouldn't Use Winter Tires Year-Round
>
> Winter tires are specially designed for cold temperatures and winter precipitation. Once it gets warm, you won't need deep tread depths to handle snow or biting edges for traction on ice. Here are some specific reasons why using winter tires year round is not recommended.
>
> **Faster wear on warm, dry pavement** - the tread rubber of winter tires is considerably more flexible than that of all season and summer tires. That same pliable tread rubber that adds traction in winter will wear down quickly in warm temperatures. Summer and all-season tires are built to withstand warm temperatures, providing long wear life.
>
> **Decreased performance** - In warm weather, winter tires won't provide the same handling capabilities as summer or all-season tires. Imagine if you needed to make a quick maneuver and your tires were soft and squishy. You won't get the crisp response from a winter tire in warm weather. Winter tires need that flexibilitity to handle ice and snow, but it's not as useful in warm weather.
>
> The specialized compounds and tread designs of winter tires are not designed for optimal warm climate performance and wear. Generally speaking, the softer tread of a winter tire will wear out faster in warmer temperatures. If you keep winter tires on your vehicle after winter has come and gone, you will have to replace them sooner than had you removed them for springtime.
>
> That’s why using snow tires year round is more expensive than mounting them seasonally. The sooner they wear out, the sooner you have to replace them.

But see [The Globe and Mail](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:xx8bswGYPXYJ:https://www.theglobeandmail.com/globe-drive/culture/commuting/is-there-a-downside-to-driving-on-winter-tires-in-the-summer/article32837461/+&cd=16&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=ca&client=firefox-b-d) Nov 15 2016.

> But one safety expert said he sticks to winter tires on warm roads.
>
> "I drove many times to Florida from Ottawa with my winter tires – I leave here in the winter and I use the winter tires while in Florida," said Raynald Marchand, general manager of programs with the Canada Safety Council, in an e-mail.
>
> Whether you're driving on winter tires or all-seasons, make sure they're at the right tire pressure for your vehicle – the numbers on the sticker inside the door. Tire pressure drops with the temperature, so, in the winter, check pressure [at least once a month](http://www.tc.gc.ca/eng/motorvehiclesafety/safevehicles-safetyfeatures-wintertires-index-468.htm?campaign=Facebook_eng).